# For which $p,q$ does the $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^p}{\mid{1-x}\mid^q}dx$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

For which $p,q$ does the $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^p}{\mid{1-x}\mid^q}dx$ exist ?

Can you help me, I have been siting hours on this question .

I got that for $ q<1$ and $p>q+1$, but I am not sure if thats right

Answer (score 2):

The only correct bound you have is $$q<1.$$ $x^p|1-x|^{-q}$ has potential issues at $0,1,+\infty$.

1. At $0$, the function is like $x^p$. need $p>-1$.
2. At $1$, the function is like $|1-x|^{-q}$. Need $q<1$.
3. At $\infty$, the function is like $x^{p-q}$. Here we need $p-q<-1$.

The result is the following triangle of admissible values: ($x$-axis is $p$, $y$-axis is $q$)

[image]

From this graph, we can verify that your answer is not right: your answer allows the values $(p,q) = (-5,-10)$. Indeed, $-10=q<1$ and $p=-5 > -10+1=q+1$. But this gives the integral
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{|1-x|^{10}}{x^5} dx$$
This integrand has a non-integrable singularity at 0, is integrable around 1, and has polynomial growth at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to get rid of the absolute value to simplify:
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^pdx}{|1-x|^q}
 = \int_0^1 \frac{x^p dx}{(1-x)^q}
 + \int_1^\infty \frac{x^p dx}{(x-1)^q}
$$
Now the first integral has a problem at $x \to 1^-$, and the second as $x \to 1^+$, and also a potential problem at $x\to \infty$, and if $p < 0$ then both of those have a problem at $x \to 0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I did it like that but I am not sure if my answer is right or partially right is there any other “requests” on q ?

Comment: Specifically around the singular point x=1

Comment: You did not consider the problem at $0$

Comment: @CalvinKhor there is no problem at 0 -- the numerator is zero and the denominator is 1

Comment: Are you suggesting that $p\ge 0$? Because this makes the integral divergent

Comment: @CalvinKhor fixed for $p <0$ explicitly

Comment: It's not really an if, $p<0$ is necessary or else the integral will explode at one of the other points. And the second integral doesn't have an issue at 0 because of how you split it? But at least it's possible to find the answer now following your sketch